# Заблокировать программу

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть приложение на WinForms. Пользователь логинится и остается в системе. После 5 мин. отсутствия нужно заблокировать программу для перелогина и продолжения работы с тогоже места или войти новым пользователем. Как правильно отследить время бездействия для блокирования и сделать разблокировку?

Comment: имеем право определить отсутствие пользователя, как отсутствие событий в формах приложения с клавиатуры и мыши? или нужно более глобально отслеживать?

Comment: просто если перестали работать с программой и прошло время болкируем

Comment: можно попробовать по событиям связанным с активными действиями пользователя фиксировать время действия и по таймеру проверять сколько времени прошло, например раз в минуту. Или по тем же событиям перезапускать таймер с заданным интервалом, но первый вариант мне нравится больше. Если подходит - оформлю как ответ

Comment: правда много лишнего кода получается, может кто что лучше предложит

Comment: Можно попробовать подписаться на события формы MouseMove и KeyPress. И по ним сбрасывать таймер. Соответственно если таймер срабатывает (по истечению времени) всё содержимое формы залочить и отобразить поле ввода пароля для разблокировки.

Comment: @Alexey проблема будет когда форм много у приложения. Если пользователь работает в дочерней форме, а в основной сработает таймер. Получается, что кроме обвязки каждой формы таймерами, нужно еще сделать обвязку для согласованной работы всех таймеров.

Comment: GetLastInputInfo

Comment: @NMD пример можно? а  то результат у меня постоянно пол секунды

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Monitorare-il-tempo-di-bba0178c Очень похоже на то что вам нужно